# Добавление записи в MySQL если такой еще нету

Tags: php, mysql

Как добавлять записи в таблицу, только в случае если такой записи еще нету(не учитывая при сравнении столбец автоинкремента).

Можно вот так:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tab` SET `tovar` = "vedro", `money` = 100;
```

но тогда автоинкремент увеличивается при каждой проверке, не смотря на то что запись не была добавлена- как этого избежать?

Какой способ проверки самый быстрый?

Comment: если insert ignore вам не подходит, тогда одним запросом select проверяете на существование записи, если нет то инсертите

Comment: *автоинкремент увеличивается при каждой проверке, не смотря на то что запись не была добавлена- как этого избежать?* Вопрос не "как", а "зачем". Но раз вопрос в такой форме возник - значит, Вы на автоинкремент наложили ещё один какой-то смысл, кроме уникального индекса записи. Это - плохо! Если нужна непрерывная нумерация - для этого следует создать дополнительно ещё одно поле, и уже в нём делать требуемое. А на автоинкремент даже не смотрите.

Comment: @Akina благодарю за ценный совет- всегда буду стараться не налагать на автоинкремент иных ролей, кроме уникального индекса записи.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
INSERT INTO `tab` (tovar, money) SELECT 'vedro', '100'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `tab` WHERE (tovar, money) IN ('vedro', '100'));
```

P.S. Вам не все равно на автоинкремент? ну и пусть себе увеличивается, вы его все равно фиг забьете.

Comment: [offtop] А всё равно будут "дырки" в автоинкременте. Пул генерированных значений никуда не денется...

Comment: В движке DLE число автоинкремента- уникальная часть ссылки(site.ru/id-имя новости.html). Чем меньше ссылка, тем лучше с точки зрения продвижения сайтов. Обычно все равно.